# How do I assign an HTML button value to a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, calculator, assign

I am making a simple calculator (add, subtract, multiply, divide). I need a way so that I can assign the button values to javascript variables so I can put together the values (i.e. a number like 12345) and so I can do the calculations. Any ideas? Note: I am a complete novice so the simpler the better, thank you.

Comment: You should show us what you have done so far to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't have anything so far, just a calculator shell.

Comment: You should learn the language instead of just asking someone how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest solution would be to just attach a handler to all buttons in a scope, read then out the text (or some data attribute) on click.

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

then do listen to click events.

```
$("#bottons button").click(function() {
    var n = parseInt($(this).text());
    // n is now the integer that was clicked.
    // do with it something :)
});
```

again, this is just the fastest example. But anyways, hope it helps.

Comment: Amazing that a "complete novice" somehow knew which library to load, and noticed that the selector was broken.

Comment: what do you mean with selector broken?